# scp with special characters programmatically

Tags: perl, bash, unix, ssh, scp

I have been searching for this for a while, and can't find a satisfactory answer.

I have a perl script that needs to copy a file from one host to another, essentially

```
sub copy_file{
    my($from_server, $from_path, $to_server, $to_path, $filename) = @_;

    my $from_location = "$from_server:\"\\\"${from_path}${filename}\\\"\"";
    my $to_location = $to_path . $filename;
    $to_location =~ s/\s/\\\\ /g;
    $to_location = "${to_server}:\"\\\"${to_location}\\\"\"";

    return system("scp -p $from_location $to_location >/dev/null 2>&1"");
}
```

The problem is, some of my filenames look like this:

```
BLAH;BLAH;BLAH.TXT
Some really nicely named file( With spaces, prentices, &, etc...).xlx
```

I am already handling whitespaces, and the code for that is quite ugly since on each side, the files could be local or remote, and the escaping is different for the from and to part of the scp call.

what I am really looking for is either to somehow to escape all possible special characters or somehow bypass the shell expansion entirely by using POSIX system calls. I am ok with writing a XS Module if need be.

I have the correct keys set up in the .ssh directory
Also I am not honestly sure which special characters do and don't cause problems. I would like to support all legal filename characters.

Comment: Can't you use SFTP? It is the simplest way to get rid of the intermediate shell(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you want to copy file `foo(s)` using `scp`.

As shown below, `scp` treats the source and target as shell literals, so you pass the following arguments to `scp`:

- `scp`
- `-p`
- `--`
- `host1.com:foo\(s\)` or `host1.com:'foo(s)'`
- `host2.com:foo\(s\)` or `host2.com:'foo(s)'`

You can do that using the multi-argument syntax of `system` plus an escaping function.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $source = $from_server . ":" . shell_quote("$from_path/$filename");
my $target = $to_server   . ":" . shell_quote("$to_path/$filename");

system('scp', '-p', '--', $source, $target);
```

If you really wanted to build a shell command, use `shell_quote` as usual.

```
my $cmd = shell_quote('scp', '-p', '--', $source, $target);
```

---

```
$ ssh ikegami@host.com 'mkdir foo ; touch foo/a foo/b foo/"*" ; ls -1 foo'
*
a
b

$ mkdir foo ; ls -1 foo

$ scp 'ikegami@host.com:foo/*' foo
*              100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
a              100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
b              100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00

$ ls -1 foo
*
a
b

$ rm foo/* ; ls -1 foo

$ scp 'ikegami@host.com:foo/\*' foo
*              100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00

$ ls -1 foo
*
```

Comment: Thanks, is the "--" just an example, or is it needed for whatever reason?

Comment: It marks the end of the options. It avoids problems if $source starts with `-`, which admittedly, doesn't seem possible in this particular scenario. It's a good habit, though; I'd rather have extra `--` than to have one missing.

Comment: Thanks, The SCP Part of My script is working, but I have a verification step which still isnt. I was wondering if you could help. The following line isn't being escaped correctly: system('ssh', $to_server, 'stat ' .shell_quote($to_location))

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to handle this:

1. Use the multi-argument form of `system` which will completely avoid the shell:

   ```
   system 'scp', '-p', $from_location, $to_location;
   ```

   Disadvantage: you can't use shell features like redirection.
2. Use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String%3a%3aShellQuote) to escape the characters.

   ```
   $from_location = shell_quote $from_location;
   $to_location   = shell_quote $to_location;
   ```

   Disadvantage: certain strings can exist which can't be quoted safely. Furthermore, this solution is not portable as it assumes Bourne shell syntax.
3. Use [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC%3a%3aRun) which essentially is a supercharged `system` command that allows redirections.

   ```
   run ['scp', '-p', $from_location, $to_location],
     '>', '/dev/null',   # yes, I know /dev/null isn't portable
     '2>', '/dev/null';  # we could probably use IO::Null instead
   ```

   Disadvantage: a complex module like this has certain limitations (e.g. Windows support is experimental), but I doubt you'll run into any issues here.

I strongly suggest you use IPC::Run.

Comment: I am not sure this will work, what about escaping on the other machine. I will give system 'scp', '-p', $from_location, shell_quote $to_location; a try

Comment: @Smartelf there is no escaping to consider on the other machine. Don't double-escape the filenames.

Comment: IIRC, $from_location and $to_location are interpreted as globs on the remote server. You need two levels of quoting. Gotta run, but I'll check on this soon enough

Comment: Re "certain strings can exist which can't be quoted safely.", Said strings couldn't be passed by any other means either, so that's hardly a disadvantage.

Comment: Yup, I remembered correctly. None of those will work. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- It's not part of the standard Perl distribution, but [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH2) and [Net::SSH2::SFTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH2%3a%3aSFTP) are two highly ranked CPAN modules that will do what you want. `ssh`, `scp`, and `sftp` all use the same protocol and the `sshd` daemon. If you can use `scp`, you can use `sftp`. This gives you a very nice Perlish way to copy files from one system to another.
- The [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) command will take a string and quote all non-text ASSCII characters for you. It's better than attempting to do the situation yourself with the `s/../../` substitution.
- You can use `qq(..)` and `q(...)` instead of quotation marks. This will allow you to use quotation marks in your string without having to quote them over and over again. This is especially useful in the `system` command.

For example:

```
my $error = system qq(scp $user\@host:"$from_location" "$to_location");
```

- One more little trick: If the `system` command is passed a single parameter, and that parameter has shell metacharacters in it, the `system` command will be passed to the default system shell. However, if you pass the `system` command a *list* of items, those items are passed to `execvp` directly without being passed to the shell.

Passing a_list_ of arguments to `system` via an array is a great way to avoid problems with file names. Spaces, shell metacharacters, and other shell issues are avoided.

```
my @command;
push @command, 'scp';
push @command, "$from_user\@$from_host:$from_location",
push @command, "$to_user\@$to_host:$to_location"
my $error = system @command;
```

Comment: `scp` and `SFTP` are two completely different protocols. Even if both are usually available there are cases when one is and the other isn't.

Comment: I wouldn't call them two completely different protocols. Both are implemented on top of the SSH protocol and can be served by the same `sshd` daemon.

Comment: Well, your sentence is confusing. Both SCP and SFTP usually use SSH as the transport layer but they do not build on top of the SSH protocol. Is similar to what happens between HTTP and TCP: TCP is usually the transport layer for HTTP but HTTP is not an extension of TCP.

Answer (score 0):

use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH):

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->scp_get($remote_path, $local_path);
```

The way arguments have to be quoted varies depending on the shell running on the remote side. The stable version of the module has support for Bourne compatible shells. The [development version](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH) available from GitHub has also support for `csh` and several Windows flavors (Windows quoteing is, err, *interesting*).

For instance:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, remote_shell => 'MSWin', ...);
```

Note that on Windows, there are string that just can not be properly quoted!